# Django request in html

Tags: python, django, http, python-3.6

I have set up django to work in my local environment. I have a python function which takes two parameters and returns data in JSON format. This is set up in my views.py and urls.py as follows:

views.py :

```
from django.http import Http404, HttpResponse
from X import calculate

def calculate_X(request, para1, text):
    #para1 is ignored on purpose
    return HttpResponse(calculate(text))
```

urls.py :

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^calculate-X/(\d+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_ ]*$)',calculate_X),
    url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='base.html')),
] 
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

In the base.html file I have a single button which should make the request to the calculate-x url as follows `/calculate-X/1/stringdataexample`

which would then create an `alert()` with the contents of the httpresponse ( JSON )

How can I make this request?

(There is another question asked here on SO however it uses request processors which do not relate to my question)

Answer (score 1):

one way could be to trigger an ajax call when you click that button, and then process the response as you wish.

The button's html could be something like this:

```
<button onclick="processCalculation()">Calculate!</button>
```

Something like this function:

```
function processCalculation(){
  var para1 = $("#params-container").val();
  var text = $("#text-container").val();
  $.ajax({
       url: "/calculate-X/" + para1 + "/" + text,
       data: {}
    }).done(function (jsonResponse) {
        alert(jsonResponse)
 });
```

}

I hope this points you on the right direction, Best regards!

Comment: I wanted to do this without using ajax and using window.location however the ajax version seems like a much better solution.